# Can a reaction produce more products than reactants?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, mole

> Q:What volume of propane is burnt for every $100 \mathrm{~cm}^{3}$ of oxygen in the reaction?
> $$
> \mathrm{C}_{3} \mathrm{H}_{8}+5 \mathrm{O}_{2} \rightarrow 3 \mathrm{CO}_{2}+4 \mathrm{H}_{2} \mathrm{O}
> $$
> (Gas volumes measured under the same conditions).

**My solution:**

For every 5 volumes of oxygen, 1 volume of propane is burnt. Therefore,
Volume of propane bumt for every $100 \mathrm{~cm}^{3}$ of oxygen $=\frac{1}{5} \times 100=20 \mathrm{~cm}^{3}$.

If we take the total composition, the volumes of reactant are in 1:5 ratio which produced products in ratio 3:4. In other words, the volumes of reactants are $\pu{20 cm^3}$ and $\pu{100 cm^3}$ which produced $\ce{60 cm^3}$ and $\ce{80cm^3}$ products respectively.

Sum of volume of reactants = $\pu{120cm^3}$ 
Sum of volume of products = $\pu{140cm^3}$

How are products produced more than reactants ?

Comment: Ever heard of decomposition reactions? One dollar decomposes into four quarters. How is it possible, when $4>1$? Well, just like that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin K. I understand that part. Like we can have two parts of CH4 = CO2 + H2. But Volume means like the amount of space a substance takes. Volume of 140 is taking more space than volume of 120.

Comment: Those are gases. A gas mostly consists of empty space anyway.

Comment: @IvanNeretin K. I understand that. Thank you. Also , about how it gets broken into parts. But still , how can the products be more than reactants. In any reaction. Or even less sometimes. There must be sth from where they either gained sth extra or lost. It’s a clear observation to any person doing these type of Q. How do I understand this part.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Even though gas takes v little space but it can’t violate law of conservation of energy.

Comment: Sure. The products can't have more energy than the reactants. But they can have more volume. There is no conservation law for that. Volume is **not** energy. They don't even start from the same letter.

Comment: It seems like you're wondering how the products can have a greater volume than the reactants without violating conservation of mass. So: In a chemical rxn, the number of atoms is conserved. That preserves conservation of mass. But, as you can see from your balanced chemical equation, the number of molecules isn't conserved (diff # on LHS vs. RHS). And the volume of a gas depends on the number of particles, which means the number of molecules, not the number of atoms (unless the gas is monatomic).  So if there are more gas molecules in the products than the reactants, the volume will increase.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Ok , So you mean mass of reactants = mass of products. Volume can be different. I agree. Just like how a tall person & healthy can take different volume or space in air but can have same mass. Right ?

Comment: @theorist K. Atoms of LHS = RHS but molecules are not.

Comment: @S.M.T Correct.

Comment: @theorist Would u like to write the answer so I can accept the Q to close it or shall I do it.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Would you like to write the answer sir or shall I write it.

Comment: Write it yourself, this is acceptable and even encouraged.

Comment: Sure, I can write an answer.

Comment: @theorist K sir. Even I can do it. Np in that. Just that it is your help , knowledge. I have written 1 answer regarding mass. You can write about the atoms point which u pointed our or as u feel. Shall I call you sir or ma’am ?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Now I'm considering maltreating a dollar banknote with a hammer until it finally decomposes into four quarters ^^'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're wondering how the products can have a greater volume than the reactants without violating conservation of mass.

So: In a chemical reaction, the number of atoms is conserved. That preserves conservation of mass. But, as you can see from your balanced chemical equation, the number of molecules isn't conserved: There are more molecules on the RHS than the LHS. And the volume of a gas depends on the number of particles, which means the number of molecules, not the number of atoms (unless the gas is monatomic).

This can be seen directly from the ideal gas law:

$$V = \frac{n R T}{p}$$ which means that, at constant $T$ and $p$, $V$ is proportional to $n$, where $n$ is the number of particles.

So if there are more gas molecules in the products than the reactants, the volume will increase.

Comment: I had a Q. In most of the Q’s I solved regarding mole concept , H2O is always taken as water(liquid) & not steam H2O. In certain Q , reactions are not given. Is there a condition when I have to assume H2O to me steam or liquid ?

Comment: *me = be in last comment.

Comment: I was assuming all your products and reactants were gaseous based on the volume calculations you gave.  Obviously if the water were liquid, the volume of the products would be less than that of the reactants.   To know for sure the phases of the reactants and products, you need the person that supplies the equation to either specify all the phases, or specify the temperature at which the reaction occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever heard of explosions? Explosions are chemical reactions of solid or liquid substances which produce a huge amount of gas in less than one second. For example, nitroglycerin is a liquid with the formula $\ce{C3H5N3O9}$, which makes dynamite. One mole of nitroglycerin weighs $227$ g and has a volume $142$ mL. The explosion corresponds to an equation like $$\ce{2 C3H5N3O9 -> 5 CO +  CO2 + 5 H2O + 6 NO}$$ There are doubts about the relative amounts of  $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ as a function of the ratio $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$. Anyway this is not the point here. The main point here is the fact that $2$ moles nitroglycerine ($0.284$ L) produces $6 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 15$ moles gas, which occupies, at $0$°C and $1$ atm, a volume of $\pu{15 · 22.4 L = 336 L}$.

$0.285$ litres of a liquid produces a gas volume more than $1000$ times bigger, during the explosion.

$\pu{1 cm^3}$  liquid produces $\pu{1183 cm^3}$ gas. But the mass is conserved.